# flatten a data frame having two columns by groupby on one column - pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a data frame as shown below

## df

```
cust_id         product
1               tv
1               phone
2               bat
2               ball
3               bat
4               ball
4               bat
4               tv
4               phone
5               tv
6               bat
7               bat
7               ball
7               tv
8               phone
8               tv
```

From the above I would like to prepare a data frame as shown below.

## Expected output:

```
cust_id        0         1            2           3         
      1        tv        phone        NaN         NaN
      2        bat       ball         NaN         NaN
      3        bat       NaN          NaN         NaN
      4        ball      bat          tv          phone
      5        tv        NaN          NaN         NaN
      6        bat       NaN          NaN         NaN
      7        bat       ball         tv          NaN
      8        phone     tv           NaN         NaN
```

I tried below code but it created the list of items as one column

```
s = df.groupby(['cust_id'])['product'].apply(list)
```

Comment: question 10 specifically

Comment: @MustafaAydın not exactly. Can you please add the answer here.

Comment: `df.assign(n=df.groupby("cust_id").cumcount()).pivot(index="cust_id", columns="n", values="product")`

Comment: @MustafaAydın Great, it worked perfectly. Thank you so much. If you wish you can add the answer and I will accept it.

Comment: uh, glad it works, but since question is closed as a duplicate, that's the preferred way (and i can't answer anyway :)), but thanks. (btw, above, different from the linked Q&A is i `assign` instead of `insert`ing to not affect `df`; but flow is the same)